# import matplotlib.pyplot indentation problems

Tags: python, matplotlib, indentation

I am new to python and wanted to try a couple of things with pyplot (my file is named `main.py`).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = open("article1.txt", "r")
    dict = {}
    ...
    ...
```

This code did work perfect yesterday. But today, when I start it, I get the following error:

```
IndetationError: unexpected indent (transforms.py, line 1)
```

and a file named `artist.py` opens and the following line is highlighted:

```
from .transforms import Bbox, IdentityTransform, TransformedBbox, \
```

I've no idea what is going on here and I would be very happy if someone could help me with this problem.

Comment: Shhare code snippets related to the error. It is not clear and difficult to help you solve your problem.

Comment: I literally posted everything that is related to the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you are actually running the good code?

```
IndetationError: unexpected inden (transforms.py, line 1)
```

^^This tells you that you have an indentation error in transforms.py at line 1 ^^

`from .transforms import Bbox, IdentityTransform, TransformedBbox, \`
First of all you should remove the '.' before transforms and '\' at the end, like so:

```
from transforms import Bbox, IdentityTransform, TransformedBbox
```

And you says that artist.py is opening up, and that is why I'm asking if you are running the good code. It seems like you are running artist.py ? ;D

Comment: The problem does not occure when I remove the import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

So I assume I am running the good code.

The "/" is there, because the import is continued in the next line.

Comment: Then show us the code with the line continuation. Note, you don't use line continuation in Python like you are doing....

Comment: Hmm maybe an installation/import error with matplotlib then?
Have you tried reinstalling via pip ? 
pip install --upgrade setuptools
pip install matplotlib

Comment: No I have not yet. Does this also work if I installed it on my USB-Drive?

Comment: Python is installed usb?
If so, I highly suggest you to install it on your system drive or at least on an hdd, it seems that installing python on usb isn't a great idea ( you can google it up ) probably because of environment variables/paths and stuff. If you have no choice but to run it via usb, you could always dual boot on a linux machine via usb with persistence ? And if you're talking about matplotlib, I'm not even sure how you would install it on a usb.
Just open up a cmd prompt and type in:

`pip install --upgrade setuptools`

and after type in:

`py -m easy_install matplotlib`

Comment: Double commenting just to mention I'm not TOTALLY sure about the usb installation thing, but if you do a more detailed search on it you might find something interesting?! I'm really suggesting you to have a stable environment before starting working, or you might regret it later if a single variable of that environment gets wrecked ! But I mean, if you find a way to make it work and everything is fine, then feel free to share your solution !